# .Net Core linq where with multiple List<int> and string

Tags: .net, linq, asp.net-core, filter, where-clause

I'm trying to do product filter for my e-commerce web site.
I want my customer to have multiple choices when he or she try to filter products. As a first thing i wanna show to my `ProductFilterViewModel` ;

```
    public class ProductFilterViewModel
    {
        public List<int> CategoryIDCollection { get; set; }
        public List<int> SubCategoryIDCollection { get; set; }
        public List<int> ChildCategoryIDCollection { get; set; }
        public List<int> VariantValueIDCollection { get; set; }
        public List<int> CategoryVariantIDCollection{ get; set; }
        public int MaxValueOfPrice {get;set;}
        public int MinValueOfPrice {get;set;}
        public string SearchValue { get;set;}
        public string VendorValue { get;set;}
        public string TagValue { get;set;}
        public int IndexValue { get;set;}
        public int PageCount { get;set;}
        public bool IsSearched { get;set;}
        public bool IsFiltered { get;set;}
    }
```

as u can see there is a 14 property about filtering products and i wanna done all of `Where(x=>x.Value==condition)` condition in just one query. For a example ;

```
DBContext.Products.Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true && x.CompanyID != 0 &&
  x.FileRepos.Count != 0 && x.Company.CompanyIsInShopping == true && 
  x.ProductIsActive == true && 
  productFilterViewModel.CategoryIDCollection.Contains(x.CategoryID)).ToList();
```

When i execute that query and when that `productFilterViewModel.CategoryIDCollection` is null, it's giving me a null exception error as normal. This is the thing im trying to solve.

I want that query to continue if `productFilterViewModel.CategoryIDCollection` list is null. Is it possible ? If it's possible then how ?

There is a filter property like 14 and if i check everything with if like : `if(productFilterViewModel.CategoryIDCollection!=null && ...etc)` its gonna be a long method and i will be repeating myself.
This is my query :

```
 public async Task<List<Product>> GetProductAllList(ProductFilterQuery productFilterQuery)
        {
            if (productFilterQuery.IsFiltered == false) //if there is a no filter 
            {
                int countOfAvailableProduct = DBContext.Products.Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true && x.CompanyID != 0 && x.FileRepos.Count != 0 &&
                    x.Company.CompanyIsInShopping == true && x.ProductIsActive==true).Count();
                int remainingOfProductCount = countOfAvailableProduct - (productFilterQuery.IndexValue * 12);
                if (remainingOfProductCount > 0 && remainingOfProductCount < 12)
                {
                    return await DBContext.Products.Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true && x.CompanyID != 0 && x.FileRepos.Count != 0 &&
                       x.Company.CompanyIsInShopping == true)
                      .Select(x => new Product
                      {
                          ProductID = x.ProductID,
                          DataGuidID = x.DataGuidID,
                          ProductName = x.ProductName,
                          ProductVendor = x.ProductVendor,
                          ProductSecondPhotoID = x.ProductSecondPhotoID,
                          ProductPrice = x.ProductPrice,
                          FileRepos = x.FileRepos.Select(f => new FileRepo
                          {
                              FileData = f.FileData,
                              FileID = f.FileID,
                              FilePhotoIsDefault = f.FilePhotoIsDefault,
                          }).Where(a => a.FilePhotoIsDefault == true || a.FileID == x.ProductSecondPhotoID).ToList(),
                          CurrencyValue = new CurrencyValue
                          {
                              CurrencyValueData = x.CurrencyValue.CurrencyValueData,
                              Currency = new Currency
                              {
                                  CurrencySymbol = x.CurrencyValue.Currency.CurrencySymbol
                              }
                          }
                      }).OrderBy(x => x.ProductID).Skip(12 * (productFilterQuery.IndexValue - 1)).Take(12 + remainingOfProductCount).ToListAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    return await DBContext.Products.Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true && x.CompanyID != 0 && x.FileRepos.Count != 0 &&
                        x.Company.CompanyIsInShopping == true)
                       .Select(x => new Product
                       {
                           ProductID = x.ProductID,
                           DataGuidID = x.DataGuidID,
                           ProductName = x.ProductName,
                           ProductVendor = x.ProductVendor,
                           ProductSecondPhotoID = x.ProductSecondPhotoID,
                           ProductPrice = x.ProductPrice,
                           FileRepos = x.FileRepos.Select(f => new FileRepo
                           {
                               FileData = f.FileData,
                               FileID = f.FileID,
                               FilePhotoIsDefault = f.FilePhotoIsDefault,
                           }).Where(a => a.FilePhotoIsDefault == true || a.FileID == x.ProductSecondPhotoID).ToList(),
                           CurrencyValue = new CurrencyValue
                           {
                               CurrencyValueData = x.CurrencyValue.CurrencyValueData,
                               Currency = new Currency
                               {
                                   CurrencySymbol = x.CurrencyValue.Currency.CurrencySymbol
                               }
                           }
                       })
                       .OrderBy(x => x.ProductID).Skip(12 * (productFilterQuery.IndexValue - 1)).Take(12).ToListAsync();
                }
            }
            else // this is the place where i wanna apply those all where conditions
            {
                int countOfAvailableProduct =  DBContext.Products.Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true && x.CompanyID != 0 && x.FileRepos.Count != 0 &&
                                  x.Company.CompanyIsInShopping == true && x.ProductIsActive == true).Count();
                int remainingOfProductCount = countOfAvailableProduct - (productFilterQuery.IndexValue * 12);
                if (remainingOfProductCount > 0 && remainingOfProductCount < 12)
                {
                    return await DBContext.Products.Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true && x.CompanyID != 0 && x.FileRepos.Count != 0 &&
                       x.Company.CompanyIsInShopping == true)
                      .Select(x => new Product
                      {
                          ProductID = x.ProductID,
                          DataGuidID = x.DataGuidID,
                          ProductName = x.ProductName,
                          ProductVendor = x.ProductVendor,
                          ProductSecondPhotoID = x.ProductSecondPhotoID,
                          ProductPrice = x.ProductPrice,
                          FileRepos = x.FileRepos.Select(f => new FileRepo
                          {
                              FileData = f.FileData,
                              FileID = f.FileID,
                              FilePhotoIsDefault = f.FilePhotoIsDefault,
                          }).Where(a => a.FilePhotoIsDefault == true || a.FileID == x.ProductSecondPhotoID).ToList(),
                          CurrencyValue = new CurrencyValue
                          {
                              CurrencyValueData = x.CurrencyValue.CurrencyValueData,
                              Currency = new Currency
                              {
                                  CurrencySymbol = x.CurrencyValue.Currency.CurrencySymbol
                              }
                          }
                      }).OrderBy(x => x.ProductID).Skip(12 * (productFilterQuery.IndexValue - 1)).Take(12 + remainingOfProductCount).ToListAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    return await DBContext.Products.Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true && x.CompanyID != 0 && x.FileRepos.Count != 0 &&
                        x.Company.CompanyIsInShopping == true)
                       .Select(x => new Product
                       {
                           ProductID = x.ProductID,
                           DataGuidID = x.DataGuidID,
                           ProductName = x.ProductName,
                           ProductVendor = x.ProductVendor,
                           ProductSecondPhotoID = x.ProductSecondPhotoID,
                           ProductPrice = x.ProductPrice,
                           FileRepos = x.FileRepos.Select(f => new FileRepo
                           {
                               FileData = f.FileData,
                               FileID = f.FileID,
                               FilePhotoIsDefault = f.FilePhotoIsDefault,
                           }).Where(a => a.FilePhotoIsDefault == true || a.FileID == x.ProductSecondPhotoID).ToList(),
                           CurrencyValue = new CurrencyValue
                           {
                               CurrencyValueData = x.CurrencyValue.CurrencyValueData,
                               Currency = new Currency
                               {
                                   CurrencySymbol = x.CurrencyValue.Currency.CurrencySymbol
                               }
                           }
                       })
                       .OrderBy(x => x.ProductID).Skip(12 * (productFilterQuery.IndexValue - 1)).Take(12).ToListAsync();
                }
            }

        }
```

I'm trying to solve that like 2 days so any help would be so good.

Comment: fwiw, those lists should probably all be `{get;private set;} = new List<int>();` Remember, things like calling a List's `.Add()` method or setting an individual list element via index _does not invoke `set`_. It's still a `get` operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about write your own extension... like this (i suggest to write both two extension, you gonna need it).

```
// Queryable
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>([NotNull] this IQueryable<TSource> query, bool condition,
        Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> whereExpression) where TSource : class =>
        condition ? query.Where(whereExpression) : query;
}

// Enumerable
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> query, bool condition,
        Func<TSource, bool> whereExpression) =>
        condition ? query.Where(whereExpression) : query;
}
```

Then use it chaining for your condition, like:

```
DBContext.Products
    .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.CompanyID != 0) // static condition, always get evaluate
    .WhereIf(MinValueOfPrice != 0, x => x.Price > MinValueOfPrice) // Optional condition
    .WhereIf(MaxValueOfPrice != 0, x => x.Price < MaxValueOfPrice) // Optional condition
    ... // Fill your rest condition
    .OrderBy().Skip().Take().ToList(OrArray,... anything you like)
```

And for better optimize, for you mapping part

```
.Select(x => new Product
                      {
                          ProductID = x.ProductID,
                          DataGuidID = x.DataGuidID,
                          ProductName = x.ProductName,
                          ProductVendor = x.ProductVendor,
                          ProductSecondPhotoID = x.ProductSecondPhotoID,
                          ProductPrice = x.ProductPrice,
                          FileRepos = x.FileRepos.Select(f => new FileRepo
                          {
                              FileData = f.FileData,
                              FileID = f.FileID,
                              FilePhotoIsDefault = f.FilePhotoIsDefault,
                          }).Where(a => a.FilePhotoIsDefault == true || a.FileID == x.ProductSecondPhotoID).ToList(),
                          CurrencyValue = new CurrencyValue
                          {
                              CurrencyValueData = x.CurrencyValue.CurrencyValueData,
                              Currency = new Currency
                              {
                                  CurrencySymbol = x.CurrencyValue.Currency.CurrencySymbol
                              }
                          }
                      })

// Extract the this part As Func<Product, Product> some where like
public static class ManualMappingWrapper
{
    public static Func<Product, Product> ProductProjection = x => new Product() // Fill the rest here
}

// Then reuse it in you query
DbContext.Products.where(something).select(ManualMappingWrapper.ProductProjection);
```

And for even furthur, I highly recommend to give [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) a shot, it have an extension that call `.ProjecTo()`, which might save you much more time.

Comment: this is the solution which i was looking for but im struggling to apply it. i will give you a feedback when i try it. I know automapper but i dont know how to use it but i will look at it too. Thank you for your answer and suggestions !

Comment: Not as hard as you think... just create a file, paste the extension there and enjoy... things will got pretty overkill when you first read automapper, but they'll pay you back much more. Have faith and good luck

Comment: i apply what u have been told but i could not apply WhereIf with IEnuramable. I'm trying to do something like ```WhereIf(productFilterQuery.CategoryIDCollection!=null,productFilterQuery.CategoryIDCollection.Contains(x=>x.CategoryID))``` but im getting delegate error on the lambda expression. Could u give me a example ?

Comment: `WhereIf(productFilterQuery.CategoryIDCollection!=null, x => productFilterQuery.CategoryIDCollection.Contains(x.CategoryID))` should do the work mate

Comment: oh, sorry for my syntax mistake. Thank u so so much for helping me. u made that young developer so happy, thank u so much.